# Whats is the easiest way to randomize sounds

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio

I have 11 sounds for each soundpack. They are named:

- testpack1.mp3,
- testpack2.mp3 and so on.

**My player initialises them with this code:**

```
    NSString * strName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"testpack%ld", (long) (value+1)];
    NSString * strPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:strName ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL * urlPath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:strPath];
    self.audioplayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:urlPath error:NULL];
```

This sounds will be played by pressing buttons. For example, I have generated 4 buttons, this 4 buttons play every time only `testpack1-4.mp3` but I want that my player takes random out of the 11 sounds. What's the easiest solution?

> Note: I don't want to repeat the mp3 unless all are played

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
int randNum = rand() % (11 - 1) + 1;
```

The formuale is like below

```
int randNum = rand() % (maxNumber - minNumber) + minNumber;
```

Comment: Exactly, and in the posted question first line of code, replace value+1 with randNum from this answer.

Comment: @iOSBeginner : ok... create an array of number that is done and check if that number is already done, call randNum again.. that's it...

Answer (score 2):

A suggestion:

It declares 3 variables as static variables, `played` is a simple C-Array

```
static UInt32 numberOfSounds = 11;
static UInt32 counter = 0;
static UInt32 played[11];
```

The method `playSound()` resets the C-Array to zero values if the counter is 0 and sets the counter to the number of sounds.
When the method is called the random generator creates an index number.

- If the value at that index in the array is 0 the sound is played, the index in the array is set and the counter is decreased.
- If the sound at that index has been played yet, loop until a non-used index is found.

  ```
  - (void)playSound
  {
    if (counter == 0) {
      for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSounds; i++) {
        played[i] = 0;
      }
      counter = numberOfSounds;
    }
    BOOL found = NO;
    do {
      UInt32 value = arc4random_uniform(numberOfSounds) + 1;
      if (played[value - 1] != value) {
        NSString * strName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"testpack1-%d", value];
        NSString * strPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:strName ofType:@"mp3"];
        NSURL * urlPath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:strPath];
        self.audioplayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:urlPath error:NULL];
        played[value - 1] = value;
        counter--;
        found = YES;
      }
    } while (found == NO);
  }
  ```